# About implementation of login function in React

Tags: reactjs, postman

I'm making a system that can login with email and password with React.js.
The backend (REST API) has already been completed by the client
The following error message occurred while implementing the code below.

When I tried it in Postman like the picture
Something that looks like a token is coming up.
Isn't what you're entering in the Authorization tab a request body?
It seems necessary to do the same as Postman instead of sending username and password as the request body on the React side
However, I don't know how to implement it. . .

[image]

The error is

```
GET https://login.xxx.com/login/ 401 (UNAUTHORIZED)
```

The whole code is below.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import  { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { apiURL } from './Default';
import logo_image from "../images/logo/logo.png";
import { useParams, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import background from "../images/background/BG.png";
import '../App.css';

import { isLoggedInOn } from "../stores/user";
import { setUserID } from "../stores/user";



const Login = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies();
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, errors } = useForm();
  
  const getJwt = async (data) =>{
    
        console.log(data)
        console.log(data.email)
        console.log(data.password)
        const email_encoded = btoa(data.email)
        const password_encoded = btoa(data.password)
        console.log(email_encoded)
        console.log(password_encoded)
        axios.defaults.headers.get['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
        await axios.get(`https://login.xxx.com/login/`,
          {
            username:email_encoded,
            password:password_encoded, 
          },
        )

        .then(function (response) {
          console.log("logged in!");
          console.log(response.data.access)

          setCookie('accesstoken', response.data.access, { path: '/' }, { httpOnly: true });

          setCookie('refreshtoken', response.data.refresh, { path: '/' }, { httpOnly: true });

          dispatch(isLoggedInOn());

          history.push('/');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("miss");
            alert("Email or Password is wrong!");
        });
      };

  return (
    <div className="container">
    <div className="row mx-auto">
      <div className="col-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
          <div className="row mx-auto logo_image">
            <img className="" src={logo_image} alt="" />
          </div>
          <div className="login-block">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(getJwt)}>
              <input placeholder='Email Address' className='form-control' {...register('email')} />
              <input placeholder='Password' className='form-control' type="password" {...register('password', { required: true })} />
              <Link to={`/`} style={{color: "white"}}>Reset password</Link><br></br>
              <input className='btn btn-block btn-primary col-12' type="submit" value="Login" />
            </form>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>




  );
}
export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

```
await axios.get('https://login.xxx.com/login', {
  auth: {
    username: data.email,
    password: data.password,
  }
  })
.then(function (response) {
```